# Passing Gitlab environment variables to Jenkins multijob

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have a Jenkins MultiJob build which I trigger using a Gitlab hook, as a result of a merge request. This build triggers two regular Jenkins build jobs.

The MultiJob build has access to a ton of Gitlab environment variables such as:
`gitlabMergeRequestId`

`gitlabSourceNamespace`

`gitlabSourceRepoURL`

What is the simplest way to make all of these available to a MultiJob build phase?

Comment: You mean Multibranch jobs?

Comment: No I mean a Jenkins MultiJob project. It's a plugin that basically runs other jobs. https://plugins.jenkins.io/jenkins-multijob-plugin

Comment: You can just use them directly in MultiJob build phases.